# Issue turning pdo column value to string | PHP

Tags: php, json, pdo

Essentially I am running the following query using pdo and formatting the results as JSON. The issue is I need column2 to always show as a string in the JSON, even though the value is a number, no other column value needs to be reformatted so I attempted to do a for loop to convert using strvalue.

```
$stmt = $pdoConnect->prepare('

    SELECT column1, column2, column3 from table1 where column1 = "tree"
');

$stmt->execute([]);


$row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach ($row as $rowvalue) {
    strval($rowvalue["column2"]);
}
    
echo json_encode($row);
?>
```

**CURRENT JSON RESPONSE:**

```
[
  {
    "column1": "tree",
    "column2": 29012,
    "column3": "foggy"
  },
  {
    "column1": "tree",
    "column2": 00930239,
    "column3": "sunny"
  },
   {
    "column1": "tree",
    "column2": 203943,
    "column3": "rainy"
   }
  ]
```

**IDEAL JSON RESPONSE:**

```
[
  {
    "column1": "tree",
    "column2": "29012",
    "column3": "foggy"
  },
  {
    "column1": "tree",
    "column2": "00930239",
    "column3": "sunny"
  },
   {
    "column1": "tree",
    "column2": "203943",
    "column3": "rainy"
   }
  ]
```

Comment: Any php based solution?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this, `ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES`

```
$pdoConnect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES, true);
```

ref: https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php

[phpfiddle](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql80/df8b4bc11f27dd24ac90fc3258f23a13/php/php81/a96236878c9da1e591c2aebe52cbfc5e/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are close, but what you are doing at the `foreach` loop is working with a *copy* of `$rowvalue`, which doesn't change anything as expected to the original value.

I'm not sure how you are storing the `00930239` with the leading zero's without being a string? ... as that will typically save as `930239` assuming an INT field type at the DB level.

Anyway, as an example of the first and last JSON values, change:

```
foreach ($row as $rowvalue) {
    strval($rowvalue["column2"]);
}
```

...to:

```
foreach ($row as &$rowvalue) { // use & as reference with $rowvalue to save the modification
    $rowvalue['column2'] = strval($rowvalue['column2']);
}
```

...which will give:

```
[
    {
        "column1": "tree",
        "column2": "29012",
        "column3": "foggy"
    },
    {
        "column1": "tree",
        "column2": "203943",
        "column3": "rainy"
    }
]
```

Example [php fiddle](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql80/2b9279aeef4b182d049ee6fb6fff6d0a/php/php81/936e58caef477ccb2e784cda4a4af180/).